# Lock widgets to desktop

Tags: kde, workspaces, widgets

I am running in the KDE plasma environment, and I have 9 workspaces. I would like to somehow set up a way to lock the widgets so that if I switch from one workspace to another, they will still be there.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting you're looking for is in System Settings -> Workspace Behavior.

In the Workspace Behavior dialog, choose the Virtual Desktops icon on the left. In the "Layout" group, you should see a checkbox labeled, *Different widgets for each desktop*.

Toggling that will enable/disable having separate widgets for each desktop.